# How to check if SignalR is using redis elasticache programmatically in C#. Is there any code to get stored key value pairs

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

Code is as below -

```
   services.AddSignalR()
               .AddStackExchangeRedis("*****.*****.com:6379", opts =>
               {
                   opts.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "SomeMessage";
                   opts.Configuration.Ssl = true;
                   opts.Configuration.AbortOnConnectFail = true;
                   opts.Configuration.ConnectRetry = 3;
                   opts.Configuration.ConnectTimeout = 30;
               })
               ;
```

subscribe looks as below

```
   public Task Subscribe(string subscriptionKey)
            {
            
            return Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, subscriptionKey);
            }
```

broadcast method look as below

```
   public Task SendMessage(SendMessageModel sendMessageModel)
          {
            return     Clients.Group(sendMessageModel.subscriptionKey).SendAsync(sendMessageModel.eventType,   sendMessageModel.payload);

          }
```

I am getting the broadcasted messages in client application and seems to be working fine, however I do not have direct access to redis database. How to verify with C# code that key value pairs are stored in redis elasticache?

I have tried a testMethod to connect to same redi elasticache and saved foo <> bar keyvalue pair in it, and could retrieve the value with key. shown in below code.

```
 ConnectionMultiplexer cluster =  ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("******.****.com:6379,connectTimeout=30000,responseTimeout=30000,ssl=true,abortConnect=true,syncTimeout=30000");
              
                IDatabase db = cluster.GetDatabase();
                
                db.StringSet("foo", "bar");
                var getResult = db.StringGet("foo");
                _loggerUtility.LogGenericMessage(LogType.DEBUG, "After getdb of calling Controller TestAsync() cluster value : " + getResult);
```

I want to do something similar to check key value pair for signal R messages but not sure what key is stored in redis cache. can you please let me know how to approach ?